# Gimp not in menu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, menu, gimp

Gimp is not in the the menu, it can be found by searching or /usr/share/applications/gimp.desktop, the file is an executable. So gimp can only be launched from the terminal.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you share the output of `dpkg --list | grep gimp`?

Comment: This will vary I believe depending on how you installed it, but Gimp shows up on my menus as "GNU Image Manipulation Program"  (18.04)

Comment: Solved! Thank you guiverc, It was under "GNU Image Manipulation Program" I was overlooking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GIMP stands for the

> GNU Image Manipulation Program

and it is by this name that it appears in the menu. If I search for 'gimp' it still shows, but listed in it's full name.